# directory with 980MB meta data, millions of files, how to delete it? (ext3)

Tags: filesystems, ext3, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rm on a directory with millions of files](https://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files)

Hello,

So I'm stuck with this directory:

`drwxrwxrwx 2 dan users 980M 2010-12-22 18:38 sessions2`

The directories contents is small - just millions of tiny little files.

I want to wipe it from the filesystem but have been unable to. My first try was:

`find sessions2 -type f -delete`

and

`find sessions2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`

but had to stop because both caused escalating memory usage. At one point it was using 65% of the system's memory.

So I thought (no doubt incorrectly), that it had to do with the fact that dir_index was enabled on the system. Perhaps find was trying to read the entire index into memory?

So I did this (foolishly): `tune2fs -O^dir_index /dev/xxx`

Alright, so that should do it. Ran the `find` command above again and... same thing. Crazy memory usage.

I hurriedly ran `tune2fs -Odir_index /dev/xxx` to reenable dir_index, and ran to Server Fault!

2 questions:

1) How do I get rid of this directory on my live system? I don't care how long it takes, as long as it uses little memory and little CPU. By the way, using `nice find ...` I was able to reduce CPU usage, so my problem right now is only memory usage.

2) I disabled dir_index for about 20 minutes. No doubt new files were written to the filesystem in the meanwhile. I reenabled dir_index. Does that mean the system will not find the files that were written before dir_index was reenabled since their filenames will be missing from the old indexes? If so and I know these new files aren't important, can I maintain the old indexes? If not, how do I rebuild the indexes? Can it be done on a live system?

Thanks!

Comment: Just keep going, ignore the memory usage. It's not like if you don't use the memory today you can use twice as much tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [rm on a directory with millions of files](https://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files/183824)

This was my answer, but there were other great answers, too:

> Would it be possible to backup all of the other files from this file system to a temporary storage location, reformat the partition, and then restore the files?

Comment: Hi jftuga - that's precisely what I want to avoid. Looking for a solution on a live system.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to move the current directory out of the way, make a new directory, and then remove the old one:

mv dirname dirname.old; mkdir dirname
   ls -ld dirname dirname.old
   #  verify the permissions are correct
   rm -rf dirname.old

This has the added benefit that you don't end up with an "rm -rf dirname" in your history that you might accidentally re-run.  :-)

"rm -rf" should remove the directory using only very little memory overhead.  But the "find" commands you've run before should also not be using a lot of overhead memory.  How are you measuring the memory use?

You aren't measuring this memory use by looking at the "free" column of the output of the "free" command, are you?  Because Linux will use unused memory for disc caching, and the top column under "free" doesn't take that into account.  Are you seeing the memory use in one of the programs?  Which one?  "ps awwlx --sort=vsz" will show you the big memory using programs, sorted with the big ones at the end...

Comment: I'm looking at top's output. Is that not a valid measure? From man top:   %MEM --  Memory usage (RES)
   A task's currently used share of available physical memory.

Comment: What in top is showing high memory usage?  The "find"?  The "xargs"?  The "rm"?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are piping it to xargs.. probably eating all your memory there.. find has a delete option

```
find sessions2 -type f -delete
```

Comment: Hi Mike, tried that as well. Same problem. I'll edit my answer. That's actually what I tried first.

Comment: Piping to xargs will not cause tons of memory to be eaten, "find" will pause when the buffer to xargs is filled, and then begin writing again when the buffer hits it's low water mark.  I believe that less than 1MB is stored "in flight" in this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm a crazy idea, I don't know if it would work. What if you try to do it in batches?
First rename the dir and create a new empty one, so new files don't get in the way.
Then output the contents of the dir. to a text file.
Then go through that file and remove 100 files at a time, sleeping and sync in between?