# Shrink/reset directory size?

Tags: linux, directory

Is there a way to shrink a directory entry?

My dovecot maildir directories have increased in size from [the default 4096](https://superuser.com/questions/142893/why-is-the-size-of-a-directory-always-4096-bytes-in-unix) to several megs, and it is messing with disk quotas.

The only way that I have found, is to delete and recreate the directory.  I am hoping there is a magical function somewhere - I am open to anything, except for hand-coded assembler.

Edit:
For posterity, to find dirents>4096:

```
 find / -type d -size +4k -printf "%s\t%p\t%i\n" | sort -nr
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303008/how-to-defragment-a-directory-on-ext3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See also [rm on a directory with millions of files](https://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files) (the original question is not directly related, but we discuss this problem there nonetheless).

As far as I'm aware, at least on ext2/3, no, there's no (online) way to shrink them short of delete + recreate.  Unmounted, several sources suggest `e2fsck -D` might work, though I can claim no personal experience with that option.

Some references for further reading:

- [This 2009 discussion on the LKML](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.kernel/c/IzFjKBtM-eg?pli=1)
- http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=120654

Comment: The first link was especially helpful: it addressed my problem specifically (mail servers), and the fact that Ted Tso weighed in on the dialogue is pretty cool ;)

Comment: Oh. But yes, I just had a root directory shrink from 2.1 MB to 114 kB by first doing `sudo e2fsck -fyDC0 /dev/mapper/cryptvolumename` followed by `sudo e2fsck -fyC0 /dev/mapper/cryptvolumename` (same without `-D`, required because `-D` does not write all metadata correctly at least in Debian stable)

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this.

`cp -al`*oldir**newdir*`&&
mv`*olddir**tempname*`&&
mv`*newdir**olddir*`&&
rm -r`*tempname*

where *olddir* is the directory you want to shrink
*newdir* and *tempname* are temporary filenames

`cp -al` creates links to the content of *olddir* in *newdir*
and the next three commands swap them with newdir and clean up.

Comment: slick. never knew about cp -l

Comment: unfortunately this doesn’t work for the root directory of a filesystem :/ but yeah, for others, this (just within mc) is what I normally do

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to delete and recreate an NFS directory to shrink its size after it had previously bloated.  In the process, I found a fairly efficient way to do this using rsync and hard links.  This method avoids copying the actual files, while still accomplishing the goal of recreating the directory with the same contents.

Since we needed to take downtime to do this operation during our maintenance window, making the rebuilt  directory available as soon as possible was important for us.  If simplicity is more important to you, change the first move command to an 'rm -rf' on the source directory, and skip the other 'rm -rf' command.

I extracted these commands from a larger process, and abstracted the directory names, so apologies if I've made a mistake in that translation.

```
mkdir /tmp/holding_dir/
rsync -ai --delete --link-dest=/path/to/source_dir/ /path/to/source_dir/ /tmp/holding_dir/
mv /path/to/source_dir/ /tmp/deleteme/
mv /tmp/holding_dir/ /path/to/source_dir/
```

Then later, we remove the directory.  Depending on size, you may need to use a more sophisticated technique to do this.  For example, using rsync with the --delete flag to sync an empty directory into this directory may be more efficient.

```
rm -rf /tmp/deleteme/
```