# Will running multiple rm command make deleting files faster?

Tags: linux

I have 800GB of data to delete and I entered below command

`rm -rf /data`

On my process monitor I see `rm` command running but its slow. If I ran another `rm -rf /data` command will the deletion process be faster? Or this will make things slower. I am running this on 2 core machine.

Comment: A number of interesting suggestions are in [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/183821/37681)

Comment: If your disks are HDD (not SSD), then running two `rm` in parallel will definitely *slow down* the system, because the HDD needs to move back and forth between two processes

Comment: @porton I am on SSD.

Comment: @HBruijn This is good read. I am going to try rsync --delete